# General Term for Incoming/Outgoing

Tags: single-word-requests, hypernyms

I am creating a table for managing my payments. 
There is a column that will have one of two values: **Incoming** or **Outgoing**. Is there a suitable table header for these two terms, in relation to payments? My best answer would be something like 'Payment Direction', which feels clumsy.

Edit: I hope my question is suitable. This is my first time on your forum :)

Comment: *Cash Flow*, with '+/-' or 'in/out'. But a simpler approach would be to eliminate this column and sign the amounts, '+' for revenue and '-' or '(..)' for expenditures. Traditionally expenditures are posted in red, which would mark the difference even more strongly.

Comment: *Naming* is explicitly off-topic, because you could call your database column `susan` and it would work just as well. However, asking for a [hypernym](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/hypernym) for directions is on-topic. If you could eliminate mention of naming and include the word *hypernym* which I added as a tag, it would reduce the risk of close votes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the options I find is:

> **Payment Instruction**

where you can specify the transaction as "Incoming" or "Outgoing".

Comment: Except flow of money is a good hypernym, right?...I suggest the answerer puts that part of his answer near the top.

Comment: @thomj1332 I edited my answer to fit the question. Also added in "Money Flow" as an option. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**balance sheet**

> A statement of the assets, liabilities, and capital of a business or
>   other organization at a particular point in time, detailing the
>   balance of income and expenditure over the preceding period. [ODO](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22balance+sheet%22)